# UB 12.04 Desktop - System Update Server Main vs UK and DNS

Tags: 12.04, networking, updates, dns

I am very new to Ubuntu :)

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 - 
My system detected (correctly) that I am resident of the United Kingdom
and so it/I set my update server to the United Kingdom server.

However, this was not a good choice for the following reason:

According to the UK update server my system requires some 270 updates.
However, when I try to install them I receive the message that "these 
updates would be from unauthenticated sources" and then refuses to
install any updates.

I did some reading and found that it is recommended I use the "Main"
server for updates, so I changed to "Main" and ran the update process
again, only to find that my system is FULLY up to date and there are
ZERO outstanding updates to apply to my system.

OK .. so that solved something which really should not be a problem 
in the first place.  It would be nice to see the UK update server 
bought "up to date". (Some technical irony here, for those who noticed)

So, I moved on to my next task ..

However, since changing to the "Main" server for updates my system
is no longer respecting my DNS setting and so I can not continue.

My DNS setting is set to a local (intranet DNS server) located on
my local subnet (ie 192.168.1.11/32 in this case), however, when
I try to run the update process (or any sudo apt-get process) my
system starts trying to connect to DNS servers outside of my LAN.

Due to technical policies, I have been given temporary egress to
these external DNS servers.

What I would like to know is:

Is it possible to force all Ubuntu DNS requests to respect the 
DNS server configured by my network settings.
IE. All DNS requests go to my LAN DNS server at 192.168.1.11

### Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for updated server:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As far as forcing DNS, try this:

You can edit your `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`, and add the DNS servers to the "prepend" line; this will ensure that the DNS servers are used everytime.

Open terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
```

Change this:

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1; and change it to read
```

To this:

```
prepend domain-name-servers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Replace the XXX, and YYY to reflect the DNS servers you want.

To test, you can either restart, or logout, and log back in, or just give the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

You can also set dns-* options in your interfaces file, to use the DNS of choice.

Comment: To be honest i have given up with the destop version of ubuntu

Comment: Why?  What's wrong?  Is something still not working?